# How to sync ApplicationSet using ArgoCD?

Tags: argocd

When I look at the `argocd` man, `argocd appset` does not list `sync` command:

```
$ argocd appset
Manage ApplicationSets

...

Available Commands:
  create      Create one or more ApplicationSets
  delete      Delete one or more ApplicationSets
  get         Get ApplicationSet details
  list        List ApplicationSets
```

I can sync the parent application:

```
$ argocd app sync argocd/contra-application-sets
```

but that updates all application sets defined under it:

```
...

Message:            successfully synced (all tasks run)

GROUP        KIND            NAMESPACE  NAME                           STATUS  HEALTH   HOOK  MESSAGE
argoproj.io  ApplicationSet  argocd     contra-mother                  Synced  Healthy        applicationset.argoproj.io/contra-mother unchanged
argoproj.io  ApplicationSet  argocd     gaia-test                      Synced  Healthy        applicationset.argoproj.io/gaia-test unchanged
argoproj.io  ApplicationSet  argocd     gaia-review                    Synced  Healthy        applicationset.argoproj.io/gaia-review unchanged
```

How do I limit sync to `gaia-test` `ApplicationSet` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a bit to figure out, so here is the relevant flag:

```
--resource stringArray                  Sync only specific resources as GROUP:KIND:NAME or !GROUP:KIND:NAME. Fields may be blank and '*' can be used. This option may be specified repeatedly
```

As seen from the output above, this can be therefore achieved with:

```
argocd app sync argocd/contra-application-sets --resource 'argoproj.io:ApplicationSet:gaia-test'
```